# DB2 - LUW 8.2 Can you restore one tablespace from a full DB backup to a different server

Tags: backup, db2, recovery, tablespace

In DB2 8.2 for LUW can you restore one tablespace to a 2nd server from a full database backup without having to restore the entire database? The database backup was taken when the system was up so log files are involved. I can provide further clarification if needed.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't restore the tablespace into an existing database;  however, you can restore only the system catalog tablespace (SYSCATSPACE), a temporary tablespace (like TEMPSPACE1) and the tablespace you want into a new database.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Exactly what I wanted to know.